# Adding horizontal space between list in 2 columns to make it center

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I have an unordered list which appears off-center. I want the list items on the right to be equally spaced from the right edge of the screen as the ones on the left. Right now, the entire list is skewed to the left. I want to keep the width of the items the same (to have the sentences on one line instead of two lines). How can I add more spacing between the list items to make the list items appear more evenly aligned?

[SEE THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTduh.png)

```
.fin_aid_container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.fin_aid_list {
  column-count: 2;
}

<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; margin:0px auto; padding-right:20px; "class="">
    <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><![endif]-->
    <div class="fin_aid_container" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
      <div style="color:#000000; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:21px;">
        <ul class="fin_aid_list" style="display:inline-block;">
          <li>State and federal student aid</li>
          <li>Scholarships and grants</li> 
          <li>Employer reimbursement</li>
          <li>Military and veteran benefits</li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a table instead of a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you dabbled with `flexbox`? It seems like that may be the appropriate answer here for what you are trying to accomplish.

by setting you `.fin_aid_list` to `display: flex` you can then set the child items to be evenly spaced apart. The child items in order to all be aligned on the right and left together is to make them the same size with the shorthand `flex` and setting the `flex-bias` to the same size.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trevans24/0n2hftzj/1/) here.

As a side note, it would suggest you remove inline styling and use a style sheet with classes set on your elements. It creates a better reading of your code and then you don't have to try to override another styling with `! important`